# Prevent Vite from interpolating env-var-like strings

Tags: vite

Hi guys I am working on a vite project where I need to use esbuild-wasm to build some user-provided code. I have some code like

```
import * as esbuild from "esbuild-wasm" 
// some initialization 
await esbuild.build({
  // other configurations
  define: {"process.env.NODE_ENV": "production"}
})
```

where the define key should set env vars for esbuild-wasm. But when I run vite to serve locally the "process.env.NODE_ENV" is being interpolated by vite to become ""development"" in the browser, which causes syntax error. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?